# How to dynamically set an expiry-time for a button using PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

I have buttons that says `Accept` and should be valid only for `72 HOURS` from the time of creation, and past 72, it should get disabled automatically with a message in `<span>`.

PHP:

These are my time collecting variables

```
$original_datetime = new DateTime($_item['updated_at']);
$expire_time = $original_datetime->modify("+72 hours");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="acceptBtn" value="<?php echo $this->__('Accept') ?>" 
data-created-at="<?php echo $original_datetime->format("d-M-Y H:i:s"); ?>" 
data-expiring-at="<?php echo $expire_time->format("d-M-Y H:i:s"); ?>" ><br>
<span id="expired_message"></span>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    disableAcceptButton();
}
function disableAcceptButton() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery("#acceptBtn").prop("disabled", true).hide();
        jQuery("#expired_message").text('Sorry, time expired, if you wish to buy/sell this Product again, Contact Admin via Email');
    }, 10000);
}
```

Instead of `10000` i.e 10 seconds, this should expire 3 days from creation.

Help.

Comment: jquery wont help because user cannot open a page for 3 days... you have to save the date on db

Comment: Calculate the "end" date and store it in a DB, then when ever the page / button is called, check whether the button is still valid.

Comment: Can you show me the $expire_time var format ?

Comment: @MohamedBelal same as original.. `$expire_time->format("d-M-Y H:i:s");`

Comment: @Epodax, should I control the whole functionality just form `PHP` ?

Comment: You should save start time in db and then send periodic requests from ajax to check if the time limit has expired

Comment: what @Babar suggested is a good way to do it, however it should also be possible to obtain the functionality purely in php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually you won't be able to do this with jQuery setTimeout() function you need something more stable than it

you can do this with PHP inside JS script Block:

```
<script>
<?php
$current_time = time();
//connect to db 
// check if there is no expire timestamp in db
if($thereIsNoTimestampInDB){
  $expire_time = $current_time + (24 * 60 * 60 * 3); // increase 3 days to timestamp
//save timestamp to database 
}else{
//get Timestamp from DB and save it to $expire_time
if($expire_time > $current_time){
echo "var expired=true;\n";
}else{
echo "var expired=false;\n";
}
}
?>
</script>
```

then with JS:

```
<script>
if(expired){
$("#Button").html('Sorry Button Expired, Please Contact Admin');
}
</script>
```

Comment: if you find my answer is correct please mark it as correct answer for this question